# Xcode asset catalog compiled size

Tags: ios, xcode, xcasset

I have noticed weird behavior with compiled xcassets. It looks like images in .car file are larger then default images. Here is image catalog i have used for testing https://www.dropbox.com/s/h544p42qfwjwm4y/Images.xcassets.zip?dl=0

This is somehow related to actool internals. I have tried to compile it manually: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool Images.xcassets --platform iphoneos --minimum-deployment-target 8.2 --print-contents --compile folder` and car size is larger than xcassets. Furthermore, I decompressed car file with [Crunch](http://pragmaticcode.com/crunch/) and image is about 3 times larger.

What might be a reason for this?